# Using JQuery with a rollover and transparent sprite

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using Remy Sharp's [excellent tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-fade-revisited/) to create a rollover menu using sprites, CSS and JQuery. The JQuery is solely used to ease the rollover with a fade effect and works perfectly with an opaque image sprite. However, I am having great difficulty in modifying the JQuery to work with my transparent PNG, as the original 'off-state' image still shows underneath.

I imagine the only way I can correct this is by fading out the bottom image as the top one fades on. Unfortunately any attempt I've made at this hides everything. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Please see my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehVXZ/15/) for an example.

Comment: You should add a quick jsFiddle.  It will make it much easier for others to see your problem and help you get it fixed faster.

Comment: Thank you @DadeLamkins, I've updated with a jsFiddle.

Comment: I'd use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions) where it's supported, then revert to JS for the older borwsers.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. I believe it is however currently impossible to fade between background-images using CSS transitions.

Comment: Could you use sprites and animate the background-position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a different structure. For example:

[Is this what you wanted?](http://jsfiddle.net/DNekZ/)

I only quick-modified your code so it's a bit ugly. Basically, I removed the background of the container element ('a.home') and added another span with the off-state image below it ('$off'). The span within the container is used to show the hover image ('a.home span.hover').

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Shomz, that's exactly what I was after.